# How to index data using elasticSearch in grails without domain class

Tags: json, grails, file-io, indexing, elasticsearch

I have to index data in elasticsearch using grails.

From what I understand only domain object can be indexed using the grails plugin. Is there a utilclass or a service to index arbitrary JSON data which I do not want stored in DB?

So far I have seen following methods for indexing, but all of them seem to require domain objects for indexing.

```
// Index all searchable instances
elasticSearchService.index()
// Index a specific domain instance
MyDomain md = new MyDomain(value:'that')
md.save()
elasticSearchService.index(md)

// Index a collection of domain instances
def ds = [new MyDomain(value:'that'), new MyOtherDomain(name:'this'), new MyDomain(value:'thatagain')]
ds*.save()
elasticSearchService.index(ds)

// Index all instances of the specified domain class
elasticSearchService.index(MyDomain)
elasticSearchService.index(class:MyDomain)
elasticSearchService.index(MyDomain, MyOtherDomain)
elasticSearchService.index([MyDomain, MyOtherDomain])
```

Comment: What "data" you want to index?

Comment: You can assume any json string.

Comment: In that case, you have to use the elastic search API (either the JAVA/Groovy api or REST API) to create mapping, filters and indexes. The answer to this question would be stretched if you could not get as mentioned on [how to create an index here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-create-index/).

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using [Low level API](http://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-gorm-plugin/guide/7.%20Low%20level%20API.html)

This code works for me:

```
         elasticSearchHelper.withElasticSearch { client ->
            String json = "{" +
                "\"user\":\"" + userName + "\"," +
                "\"postDate\":\"2013-01-30\"," +
                "\"message\":\"trying out Elastic Search\"" +
                "}";

            def response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet")
                .setSource(json)
                .execute()
                .actionGet()
        }
```